# How to upload captured image from Camera to a webview

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, android-camera, jfilechooser

I have this html which works perfectly if I open it with chrome application and let the user to make a photo with the camera and upload it. After selecting the photo captured by the camera, the name of the file is displayed and with the submit button I can upload the photo.

```
<html>
<body>    
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" accept="image/*"   name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>    
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that if I open this website on a webview on an android application, then, the camera is openned, yes, but after accepting the image captured, then, the image is not being passed to the html, and can't upload it. "no file chosed" message is being  displayed.

This is the sourcecode of my webview object:

```
        webView=new WebView(ctx);           
        webView.loadUrl(URLParser.parse(this.url));

        webView.getLayoutParams().height=LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        webView.getLayoutParams().width=LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(allowJavascript);
        webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(allowZooming); 
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(allowZooming);
        CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(allowCookies);

        webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
            public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                i.setData(Uri.parse( url ));                
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                ApplicationContextProvider.getContext().startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin, android.webkit.GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
                callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
            }

            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
            public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> uploadMsg, WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams){

                // Store all the mime types in an array
                String inputAcceptParameter = fileChooserParams.getAcceptTypes()[0];
                String[] mimeTypes = inputAcceptParameter.split(",");
                boolean isImage = false;
                for(String mimeType : mimeTypes) {
                    if(mimeTypes[0].equals("image/*"))
                        isImage = true;
                }

                uploadMsgCopy = uploadMsg;

                if(isImage) {
                    Util.launchExternalCameraGalleryChooserApp(Constants.WEB_INPUT);
                } else {
                    Util.launchExternalBrowser(Constants.WEB_INPUT);
                }

                return true;
            }

        });

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            boolean isFirstLoad = true;

            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                if(AdManager.getInstance().hasAds() && isFirstLoad == false && AdManager.getInstance().interstitialIntervalExceeded())
                    AdManager.getInstance().showInterstitial(ctx);
                isFirstLoad = false;
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {                         
                if( url.startsWith("browser:") ){
                    launchBrowser( url.substring(8));
                }else if( url.startsWith("market:") || url.endsWith(".pdf")){
                    launchBrowser( url );
                }else if( url.startsWith("https://www.google.com/maps/") || url.startsWith("http://maps.google") || url.startsWith("https://maps.google")){
                    try {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                        SectionManager.getInstance().getCurrentActivity().startActivity(intent);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }else if (url.startsWith("tel:")) {
                    try {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse(url)); 
                        SectionManager.getInstance().getCurrentActivity().startActivity(intent);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }else if(url.startsWith("mailto:")){
                    MailTo mt = MailTo.parse(url);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { mt.getTo() });
                    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, mt.getBody());
                    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, mt.getSubject());
                    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, mt.getCc());
                    intent.setType("message/rfc822");
                    SectionManager.getInstance().getCurrentActivity().startActivity(intent);                
                }
                return true;
            }               

            //This method launches the phone's Internet browser with the URL passed as parameter
            //@param url            
            private void launchBrowser( String url ){
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                i.setData(Uri.parse( url ));                
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                ApplicationContextProvider.getContext().startActivity(i);
            }

            @Override
            public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
                super.onReceivedSslError(view, handler, error);
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(SectionManager.getInstance().getCurrentActivity(), R.string.SSL_ERROR, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                toast.show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                String webUrl = webView.getUrl();
                // This if solve a bug with (Facebook plugins for web pages) like buttons or comments
                if (url.startsWith("https://m.facebook.com/plugins/close_popup.php")) {
                    view.goBack();
                    return;
                }
                super.onPageFinished(view, webUrl);
            }
        });
```

This is my method for launching the camera:

```
    /**
     * Launch an selection of all available ACTION_PICK "gallery" intents (external APP) to select an file.
     * Also add the IMAGE_CAPTURE "camera" intent to selection if the device has an camera.
     * If they don't have an APP of type ACTION_PICK, they try to launch an APP of type IMAGE_CAPTURE
     * @param onActivityResultCode the result code returned to onActivityResult when the intent has finish his job
     */
public static void launchExternalCameraGalleryChooserApp(int onActivityResultCode){

    Activity activity = SectionManager.getInstance().getCurrentActivity();

    Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    Intent takePictureIntent =  new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);


    if(galleryIntent.resolveActivity( activity.getPackageManager()) != null ) {

        Intent[] intentArray = new Intent[0];
        if(takePictureIntent.resolveActivity( activity.getPackageManager()) != null ){
            intentArray = new Intent[] { takePictureIntent };
        }

        Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, galleryIntent);
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Image Chooser");
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);
        activity.startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, onActivityResultCode);

    } else if(takePictureIntent.resolveActivity( activity.getPackageManager()) != null ) {

        Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, galleryIntent);
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Camera Chooser");
        activity.startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, onActivityResultCode);

    }
}
```

And this is the source of my onActivityResult method:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    switch (requestCode){
        case Constants.WEB_INPUT:
            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
                Uri[] results = null;
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) { //&& intent != null
                    if (uploadMsgCopy == null) {
                        return;
                    }
                    if (intent != null) {
                        String dataString = intent.getDataString();
                        if (dataString != null)
                            results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(dataString)};
                    }
                }
                uploadMsgCopy.onReceiveValue(results);
                uploadMsgCopy = null;
            }
            break;
        default:
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue?

Comment: @Jack same question. It would be very helpful.